# Manipulate file path for output using split

Tags: powershell

I have a file path

```
e:\pst\Section\RMS\user\\
```

final output needs to be Section/user

Currently using

```
$result.filepath = $pst.FilePath.Split('\')[2..4] -join '/'
```

but that gives me

```
Section/RMR/User
```

How can I manipulate the split to only pull 2 and 4 to equal Section/User?

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your example:

```
$pst = 'e:\pst\Section\RMS\user\'
$result.filepath = $pst.FilePath.Split('\')[2..4] -join '/'
$result.filepath
Section/RMS/user
```

Should be:

```
$pst = 'e:\pst\Section\RMS\user\'
$result.filepath = $pst.FilePath.Split('\')[2,4] -join '/'
$result.filepath
Section/user
```

Note the comma instead of the range operation.

Comment: Thanks.I got it to work using  $result.filepath = $pst.FilePath.Split('\')[2,4] -join '/ -replace('RMS/') but i like your solution better